# Ember Array contains not working with Fixture

Tags: ember.js

I am trying to check if a Model is contained in a collection of models, but somehow even if the collection contains my searched models the contains check still fails (myFriendshipStatus):

```
    var attr = DS.attr;

GambifyApp.User = DS.Model.extend({
    firstName: attr(),
    lastName: attr(),
    nickName: attr(),
    image: attr(),

    friendsWithMe: DS.hasMany('user', {
        inverse: 'myFriends', async: true
    }),
    myFriends: DS.hasMany('user',{
        inverse: 'friendsWithMe', async: true
    }),
    groups: DS.hasMany('group', {async: true}),

    fullName: function() {
        return this.get('firstName') + ' ' + this.get('lastName');
    }.property('firstName', 'lastName'),

// Ember.computed.intersect('myFriends', 'friendsWithMe')
    friends: function() {
        var ret = [];
        Ember.RSVP.all([this.get('myFriends'), this.get('friendsWithMe')]).then(function(results) {
            ret.pushObjects(_.intersection(results[0].get('content'), results[1].get('content'))) ;
        });
        return ret;
    }.property('myFriends', 'friendsWithMe'),


    /**
     *  Gives the relation between two User
     *  4: has requested your friendship
     *  3: Yourself
     *  2: Friends
     *  1: FriendShip Request
     */
    myFriendshipStatus: function() {
    if(this.get('friends').contains(GambifyApp.User.Current)){
        return 2
    } else if(this.get('friendsWithMe').contains(GambifyApp.User.Current)){
        return 4
    } else if(this.get('myFriends').contains(GambifyApp.User.Current)){
        return 1
    } else if (this.get('id') === GambifyApp.User.Current.id){
        return 3
    } else {
        return 0
    }
    }.property('myFriends', 'friendsWithMe')
});
```

Those are the fixtures I am using:

```
GambifyApp.User.FIXTURES = [
    { id: 1, firstName: 'Marc', lastName: 'Höffl', nickName: 'marc',
        image: 'images/fixtures/Profile/marc.jpg',
        friendsWithMe: [2, 3],
        myFriends: [2, 3],
        groups: [1, 2]
    },
    { id: 2, firstName: 'Tobias' , lastName: 'Degele', nickName: 'degi',
        image: 'images/fixtures/Profile/degi.jpg',
        friendsWithMe: [1, 3, 4, 5],
        myFriends: [1, 3],
        groups: [1, 2]
    },
    { id: 3, firstName: 'Franz' , lastName: 'Herbert', nickName: 'Hubi',
        friendsWithMe: [4],
        myFriends: [1,2, 3,4,5],
        image: 'images/fixtures/Profile/MOF.jpg',
        groups: [1]
    },
    { id: 4, firstName: 'Christian' , lastName: 'Ditter', nickName: 'Dyder',
        friendsWithMe: [3, 5],
        myFriends: [2, 3, 5],
        image: 'images/fixtures/Profile/user.png',
        groups: [ 2]
    },
    { id: 5, firstName: 'Strego' , lastName: 'Pengo', nickName: '!',
        friendsWithMe: [3, 5],
        myFriends: [2, 4, 5],
        image: 'images/fixtures/Profile/diggity.jpg',
        groups: [ 2]
    }

];
```

This is my Fixture for the currently logged in User:

```
GambifyApp.User.Current = GambifyApp.User.FIXTURES[0]
```

I have debugged the contains function and I see that the searched model is contained in my collection but it still isn't found.

**Update**
I have now solved it not via global but by injecting the user in all controllers:

```
Ember.Application.initializer({
  name: "currentUser",

  initialize: function(container, application) {
    var store = container.lookup('store:main');

    container.optionsForType('user', { instantiate: false, singleton: true });
    container.register('user:current', store.find('user', 1));
  }
});

Ember.Application.initializer({
  name: "injectCurrentUser",
  after: 'currentUser',

  initialize: function(container) {
    container.injection('controller:application', 'currentUser', 'user:current');
    container.typeInjection('route', 'currentUser', 'user:current');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

contains tells you whether the exact object is in there.   Ember Data wraps the fixture data with the DS.Model and all of it's extra magic (dirty checking, saving, etc).  So the POJO is not going to be found.

So you'll be better off finding the record (using the store) and assigning it

```
GambifyApp.User.Current = this.store.find('user', 1);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks that was already my suspicion. I am currenty prototyping and therefore have a very unclean architecture. My GambifyApp.User.Current is just defined as global and where I define it, I don't have access to "this.store". I already tried: "GambifyApp.Store.find('user',1)" and GambifyApp.User.find(1), but in each case it throws an exception: Uncaught TypeError: Object function () { ..... } has no method 'find'

Comment: I'd probably move it to the application route for now, it's a good entry point with access to the store.